# Format to set active font

Tags: quill

I can use format to set the current font size and color
  quill.format('size', '18px');
  quill.format('color', 'red');
but when I try to set the font name eg.
  quill.format('font', 'Cursive');
it has no effect. The font, in this case 'cursive', exists in the font dropdown in the tool bar (and if you select it, it does become the current font).

How can I use format to set the active font?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it's case sensitive. This

```
quill.format('font', 'Cursive');
```

doesn't work but this does

```
quill.format('font', 'cursive');
```